# Check if a ball is inside a circle drawn by a line

Tags: c#, math, unity-game-engine

I'm new with Unity and I need to know how to check if a ball is inside a circle drawn by a line. I keep the collision points of each point of the line in an array to detect if it goes into collision with the ball, and each point of collision has its X - Y points and I need to know if the user has managed to surround the ball with the line that he has drawn.

If you can help me with a little code I would appreciate it.

Thank you.

Comment: You have to show us what you've already tried. For now it is more of a mathematical question than a programming one.

Comment: I tried to check all the collision points drawn by the line with the coordenates X - Y of the ball with a "for"... but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It is not quite clear - what is "a circle drawn by a line"?

In any case, circle has a center C and radius R, ball has center bc, radius br, distance between centers `D = Sqrt((bc.X-C.X)*(bc.X-C.X) + (bc.Y-C.Y)(bc.Y-C.Y))`

Ball:
does not intersect the circle if distance between centers is more than radius sum

```
D > R + br
```

touches the circle, if

```
D = R + br
```

intersects it, if

```
R - br <  D < R + br
```

lies inside fully if  (assuming br <= R)

```
R - br >=  D
```